# SQL query regarding test

Tags: sql

i would really appreciate if someone could help me. I need to generate two SQL queries.

Assuming i have a database with this fields
Client_number, Account_number, Age, Account_balance_statement

How do i generate a query with the number of accounts and their total balance statement per client

How do i generate an average balance statement per client with an age equal or greater than 22 years

Thank you

Comment: Provide some sample data to work on it and also the expected results?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions like these are [too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Try asking [minimal specific questions about programming issues](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), by splitting your problem into smaller questions. If you require tutorials and courses on how to accomplish your goals, unfortunately Stack Overflow is not the right place to do it.

Comment: Client_number, Age,  Account_number, account_balance_statement
1 23 1001  $4,000 
1 23 1002  $3,000 
1 23 1003  $2,000 
2 34 2001  $5,500 
2 34 2002  $3,500 
2 34 2003  $2,500 
3 18 3001  $9,000 
3 18 3002  $2,000 
3 18 3003  $3,000 
3 18 3004  $8,000

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(Account_number),
       sum(Account_balance_statement)
FROM yourtable
```

and

```
SELECT Client_number,
       Age,
       avg(Account_balance_statement)
FROM yourtable
WHERE Age >= 22
GROUP BY Client_number, Age
```

This should do it, right?

Comment: one question in the first query, do i need to add group by Client_number?

Comment: yeah, that should do it

Comment: Thank you @Vaidøtas Ivøška for helping me